# sfml keyboard condition or

Tags: c++, sfml

I am a beginner in progamming in c++

And i tried to animate my character when i press the button.

so i wrote this :

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up||Down||Left||Right)
{...
```

i found a solution but it's compliquated

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)||sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)||sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)||sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
```

I would like to know why my first try don't work ? and how i can do for do that simple as possible ?

Comment: Why do you think first solution would work? It seems you should start with [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You could add `using namespace sf::Keyboard;` to avoid repeating this part each and every time, but otherwise it's as simple as it can be (and as your API allows). You could also extract this to a function (i.e. `isArrowKeyPressed()`), then you'd just need to call this function.

Comment: Also you can use `std::any_of`.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: No there really no way around having to write your "complicated" condition.

---

The general syntax of the logical or operator is `<expression> || <expression>`.

With `sf::Keyboard::Up||Down` the left-hand side is indeed an expression, but the right-hand side isn't. It's just a symbol that probably aren't even declared, and as such will not compile.

---

The result of the logical or operator is a `bool` value, either `true` or `false`. The value `true` can be implicitly converted to `1` and `false` to `0`. In the opposite direction all non-zero values are implicitly convertible to `true` while only `0` is convertible to `false`.

If we take the whole expression `sf::Keyboard::Up||Down||Left||Right`, and assume that the symbols would be valid without any scoping, the that expression is equal to `((sf::Keyboard::Up||Down)||Left)||Right`.

Now as to how evaluate that expression, it depends on the values of those symbols. But if we assume that only *one* might possibly be zero, the we have

- `sf::Keyboard::Up||Down` which will be `true`
- `true||Left` which will be `true`
- `true||Right` which will be `true`.

So your condition

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up||Down||Left||Right))
```

would really be

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(true))
```

which is equal to

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(1))
```

which using [the `Key` enumeration](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#acb4cacd7cc5802dec45724cf3314a142) would be equal to

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::B))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer only answers your second question. For the first question have a look at Some Programmer Dude's answer.

You can try it with a `using namespace` block:

```
int main() {
  // some code
  {
    using namespace sf::Keyboard;
    if(isKeyPressed(Up)    || isKeyPressed(Down) || 
       isKeyPressed(Right) || isKeyPressed(Left)) {
      //some stuff
    }
  }
  //more code
}
```

In easy words the `using namespace sf::Keyboard` adds `sf::Keyboard` to everything where the compiler thinks it makes sense (or better: it adds it if there is a function that fits in that namespace).

[You can read up more here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) At the bottom they use it pretty similar to what I did.

Comment: Ok ty, but someone said me that us `using namespace` isn't advisable. 1 or 0 so ?

Comment: @Jules Somehow yes, but not (that much) in this case. [Here you can see why it is considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). It can be bad if you use it globally. If you are using a namespace inside of { }, you limit its use to this tiny space. The possibility that you get a misinterpretation is much smaller this way. You still have to be a bit mindful.